# Compare element in SQL ( Room Reservation WebApp) Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, eclipse

I have created a simple web application.
I need to check, when someone books a room, that the arrival_date is different.
For instance:
Person A: books a room in data: 12/07/2018
Person B: book a room in data: 12/07/2018 ( HE CAN'T because there is the person A yet).

I have this db:

> hotel_booking
>
> cid, cname, email, arrival_date, departure_date, person, room, type_room,comment, status, uid.

and this is my code

> HotelBooking.java

```
package hotel;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


/**
 *
 * @author OOPs
 */
public class Hotelbooking extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String s1 = request.getParameter("id");
        String s2 = request.getParameter("name");
           String s3 = request.getParameter("email");
           String s4 = request.getParameter("arrivaldate");
           String s5 = request.getParameter("departuredate");
           String s6 = request.getParameter("person");
           String s7 = request.getParameter("rooms");
           String s8 = request.getParameter("type_room");
           String s9 = request.getParameter("comment");
           String s10 = request.getParameter("status");
           
           // sesson..........
           HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
          String s11 = (String)session.getAttribute("sessname");

       out.println(s11);
             
         
   
          
       try {
           
           
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      //  out.println("driver loaded");
     Connection  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/HotelReservation","root" ,"123456789");
      //  out.println("Connect");
      Statement  st =  con.createStatement();
        //  out.println("conncetion successfull");
     
       
       int rs =  st.executeUpdate("insert into hotel_booking (cname,email,arrival_date,departure_date,person,room,type_room,comment,status,uid)values ('"+s2+"','"+s3+"','"+s4+"','"+s5+"','"+s6+"','"+s7+"','"+s8+"','"+s9+"','"+s10+"','"+s11+"')");
         // out.println(s1);
         // out.println(s2);
          out.println("<h1> Register sucsefulltttt </h1>");
           
          /* if(rs == 1)
           {
           out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
       out.println("alert('send successfully');");
       out.println("</script>");
       //response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
           }else{
       
       
       }*/
           
          response.sendRedirect("thankyoureg.jsp"); 
           
           
           
        }catch(Exception e){
        out.println("nahiiiiiiiiiiiii" +e);
        }
        finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

How can I do in your opinion?? Thanks for the help.

Comment: By writing code... Stackoverflow is for asking *specific* programming problems or errors, not for pasting part of your project and asking for others to write your code (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Due to that I'm voting to close this question as too broad.

Comment: I asking how can I do, I don't ask you to write the code. I want only understand. I paste my code to see the variables that I used...

Answer (score 0):

Check if a query like the following returns `0`.

```
SELECT count(*)
       FROM hotel_booking
       WHERE arrival_date <= $1
             AND departure_date > $1,
             AND room = $2;
```

If it returns `0` the room isn't occupied at the day the guest wishes to check in. Otherwise it is.

Substitute `$1` with the day the guest wishes to arrive and `$2` with the room (number or name or whatever you use).

I assumed that check in/out times are handled like:

- Check in at the evening of a given day.
- Check out in the morning of a given day. That follows a guest can check in at a day another guest checks out.

If that assumption is wrong, you'd have to tweak the comparison operators accordingly.

Also consider to use parametrized queries instead of string concatenation with unsanitized user input values. The latter is dangerous, your application is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Also parametrized queries help to find the right representation for a given data type, thus prevent errors that come from misrepresented values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had thought of something similar to your answer, the problem is that I do not know the date of arrival of a certain user. It will be him when he enters the date to see that the room for that date is occupied. I do not understand what parameter I need to use to perform this action.

Comment: @Keyz23: I'd guess the same you use for `arrival_date` in your `INSERT`...